# Get user data from a TokenCredential object (.NET)

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core

I'm building a [.NET core tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools) (Console app) that needs to access some Azure Keyvault secrets by using a [SecretClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.secrets.secretclient?view=azure-dotnet). This client needs a [TokenCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.core.tokencredential?view=azure-dotnet) for which I use [DefaultAzureCredential()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet).

The client is successfully authenticated and retrieves the secrets, but **can I know which method from the flow was used (i.e. Environment, Cache, CLI, interactive)? I want to display the username that was used for logged in**, since you might have an account in SharedCache but you might want to use another account.

```
var credentials = new DefaultAzureCredential();
var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(configuration["Authentication:KeyVaultUri"]), credentials);

// Just using the client to retrieve values
var settings = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AppSettingsKeys>((await secretClient.GetSecretAsync(configuration["Authentication:SecretName"])).Value.Value);
```

I checked the `credential` object but didn't see anything useful to get the username. I want to Console.WriteLine something like `Successfully logged in with pepe@test.com using SharedTokenCacheCredential`

Comment: Do you mean the `upn` in [access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#v10-basic-claims)?

Comment: Yes I need the `upn`, thanks. I am able to get the jwt by calling the [GetToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet#methods) method and then parsing it with a JwtSecurityHandler, but I was wondering if there is a simpler way given the TokenCredential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the `upn` by first getting the jwt with the [GetToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential.gettoken?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Identity_DefaultAzureCredential_GetToken_Azure_Core_TokenRequestContext_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) method, and then parsing it with a [JwtSecurityTokenHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytokenhandler.readjwttoken?view=azure-dotnet).
Not the approach I was looking for but it works, I was wondering if there is cleaner way.

```
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(configuration["Authentication:KeyVaultUri"]), credential);

var settings = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AppSettingsKeys>((await secretClient.GetSecretAsync(configuration["Authentication:SecretName"])).Value.Value);

var token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(
                            new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(
                                new[] { "https://vault.azure.net/.default" }));

var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var jsonToken = handler.ReadToken(token.Token) as JwtSecurityToken;
var upn = jsonToken.Claims.First(c => c.Type=="upn").Value;
```